# printing content of array row wise & columnwise

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

here is code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReadFileContents {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("rfg.txt"));
    List<float[]> list = new ArrayList<float[]>();
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] line = s.nextLine().split(" ");
        list.add(new float[] { Float.parseFloat(line[0]),Float.parseFloat(line[1]),Float.parseFloat(line[2]) });
        }  
        int numberOfRows = list.size();
        int numberOfColumns = 3; 
        float[][] floatValues = new float[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
            floatValues[i] = list.get(i);
            System.out.println(floatValues[i][0] + " " + floatValues[i][1] + " " + floatValues[i][2]);
            }
        }   
 }
```

here is .txt file:

```
5.1 3.5 1.4 2.0     
4.9 3.0 1.4 40.1    
4.7 3.2 1.3 1.4     
4.6 3.1 1.5 5.1             
5.0 3.6 1.4 4.1                 
5.4 3.9 1.7 9.4         
4.6 3.4 1.4 4.5         
5.0 3.4 1.5 3.51        
4.4 2.9 1.4 4.0         
4.9 3.1 1.5 1.45
```

it gives o/p of only 3 columns:

but i want to print the file which is having the same dimension as given in file(file with "n*m" dimension). dimensions can be changed as per the given file.

Comment: The code gives out of three columns as you are parsing only three fields? Still don't understand your question. Do you want to print the same content again?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to parse a file with a matrix of float values. You want to determine the dimensions by reading the file and storing them in a `float[][]`. Here what I believe you want:

```
File file = new File("rfg.txt");
List<float[]> list = new ArrayList<float[]>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\n");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String[] values = scanner.next().trim().split(" ");
    float[] floats = new float[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        floats[i] = Float.parseFloat(values[i]);
    }
    list.add(floats);
}

float[][] values = new float[list.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    values[i] = list.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(values[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only reading 3 columns from the text file. If the number of columns is dynamic then you can use a loop like this:

```
  while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] line = s.nextLine().split(" ");
    float[] f = new float[line.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < line.length; i++){
        float[i] = float.parseFloat(line[i]);
    } 
    list.add(f);
    numColumns = line.length;
  }
```

This way the number of columns become the number of columns in the file.